# How to determine a session variable contains data table is null or empty in C#

Tags: c#, session, datatable

I have a Session variable Session["tblItems"], The session variable holds a datatable. Please find my code below.

```
public JsonResult SaveItemToTable(string itemCode, int quantity, int Division)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("tblItems1");

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["tblItems"] as string))
            {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["tblItems"];
            DataRow[] i = dt.Select("ItemCode ='" + itemCode + "'");
            if (i.Count() > 0)
            {
                for (int j = dt.Rows.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    DataRow dr1 = dt.Rows[j];
                    if (dr1.ItemArray[0].ToString() == itemCode)
                    {
                        dr1.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Division", typeof(int));
        }

        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ItemCode"] = itemCode;
        dr["Quantity"] = quantity;
        dr["Division"] = Division;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["tblItems"] = dt;
        return Json(1);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(0); 
    }
}
```

When the Session variable is empty , the code works fine (Only for the first time).
all the times

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["tblItems"] as string))
```

The above code returns false. Even if the session variable contains value.

Comment: You are trying to cast `DataTable` to `string`? You can't just casually use methods out of their purpose and expect to get right results.

Comment: I also tried if (Session["tblItems"] != null) But this will return true for the first case too.

Comment: For the First case when the session is empty the session returns empty value, not null. For changing that I used the above code

Comment: What you mean "first time Session is not null but empty", if session with given key does not exist, it will be always null.

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable("tblItems1");
 dt = (DataTable)Session["tblItems"]; When I Give this code only by checking the session is null. It will return a cast error.

Comment: If `Session["tblItems"]` will be `null`, you will get your `dt` as `null`.

Comment: Here is example in [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bkxanY).

Comment: Please up vote my answer too, if it was indeed helpful. It helps us answerers to gain rep points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is returning false because you are using a 'safe cast': `as` casting will return null if the conversion can't be made (see more on the C# guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-safely-cast-by-using-as-and-is-operators)). Since you are trying to cast a datatable to a string, this will always return null, even when your session variable has a value.

To see the true nature of your problem, try converting them like this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["tblItems"]))
```

This should thrown an exception, because you can't convert a datatable to a string like this. You will need to test for null like this:

```
if (Session["tblItems"] != null))
```

**Update**: having seen your comments, above, I've added a fuller example to explain what need to change. Your code should look more like this:

```
DataTable dt;

if (Session["tblItems"] != null))
{
    dt = (DataTable)Session["tblItems"];
    ...
}
else
{
    dt = new DataTable("tblItems1");
    ...
}

DataRow dr;
dr = dt.NewRow();
...
```

Note the changes I've made: initialise `dt` from session if there is a value, the cast will work in this case, and when it is null, construct a new one. You can then use the value in the section below without issue, because it will always have a value.

In addition, I would also recommend that you don't store your datatable in session at all, but rather just the values that you need.

Comment: Please up vote my answer too, if it was indeed helpful. It helps us answerers to gain rep points.

Comment: I do not have essential reputations. thats y

Comment: I also clear the session variable after insertion using  Session["tblItems"] = null;

Answer (score 0):

To check if your Session is null or empty (for `DataTable`):

```
private bool IsDataTableNullOrEmpty(object arg) =>
    arg == null || ((DatTable)arg).Rows.Count == 0;
```